# Combine JSON data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop

I need to combine some data. I have an array `var company = ["Toyota", "Honda"]` and I have some corresponding data in a javascript file.

JS file:

```
var Toyota = {
  text: "Toyota",
  origin: "Japan",
  icon: "icon"
};

var Ford = {
  text: "Ford",
  founder: "Henry Ford",
  icon: "icon"
};

var Honda = {
  text: "Honda",
  models: "12"
};
```

How can read this file to only look for the elements **present in the array** and then create the JSON object that looks like below (The JSON object is two companies since Ford was not present in the array). The data of the JSON will be take from the javascript file. I am trying to write the code in javascript.

```
{ 
 "name": "Toyota",
 "origin": "Japan",
},
{
 "text": "Honda",
 "models": "12",
},
```

Thank you

Comment: The URL given to file is not found. Also you should post the content of the file in https://pastebin.com/

Comment: Thanks fixed URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
var company = ["Toyota", "Honda"];

var Toyota = {
  text: "Toyota",
  origin: "Japan",
  icon: "icon"
};

var Ford = {
  text: "Ford",
  founder: "Henry Ford",
  icon: "icon"
};

var Honda = {
  name: "Honda",
  models: "12"
};

let final = [];
[Toyota, Honda, Ford].forEach(brand => {
  if (company.includes(brand.text) || company.includes(brand.name)) {
    final.push(brand);
  }
});
```

**EDIT**
You can use the variables in a different file like so:

*File 1*

```
export var Toyota = {
  text: "Toyota",
  origin: "Japan",
  icon: "icon"
};

export var Ford = {
  text: "Ford",
  founder: "Henry Ford",
  icon: "icon"
};

export var Honda = {
  name: "Honda",
  models: "12"
};
```

*File 2* (where you will use file 1)

```
import {Ford, Honda, Toyota} from './file1.js'

var company = ["Toyota", "Honda"];
let final = [];
[Toyota, Honda, Ford].forEach(brand => {
  if (company.includes(brand.text) || company.includes(brand.name)) {
    final.push(brand);
  }
});
```

Resources that may help you understand the answer to this question:
- [Object Destruction](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment)
- [Import/Export ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: This is very helpful. Any way I can use ```[Toyota, Honda, Ford].forEach``` loop inside a different file? Since these variables are available locally to the file @Charlie

Comment: I will update my answer to tell you how you can use them in separately files

Comment: You are a savior. Thanks a lot @Charlie. I will use this as a reference since I am using angularJS, we cannot import export the way you have. But I will figure that part out by looking around :).

Comment: If the question guided you to your solution accept it as the correct answer

Comment: @netchi you have a "check mark" icon bellow the upvote button. When you click on it you mark the answer as the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Your JS file declares variables in the global scope. This means that they are not only available inside a function, but anywhere. As a result, they become properties of the `window` Object. So you can access them like so:

```
window["Toyota"]
```

Once you know this, you can do:

```
var company = ["Toyota", "Honda"];
var result = company.map(function (c) { return window[c]; });

console.log(result); // [{ "name": "Toyota", "origin": "Japan" }, ...]
```

Comment: wroth noting that anything that has `global` in their name is bad practice